# Presenting a UIActionSheet from a child UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uiactionsheet

My container view controller presents a series of subviews, each of which has its own `UIViewController`. I need to show a `UIActionSheet` when a button on one of these child views is pressed.

What is the correct way to display this action sheet from the parent view controller's toolbar? Does iOS 5's new container view controller support provide a simple way to do this? Or should I be using delegation to let the container controller know that the button was pressed?

Comment: Good question. From what I understand there is no simpler way than delegation. But someone may be wiser...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super-experienced on this question, but couldn't you just pass the `parentViewController` property as the delegate of the UIActionSheet? And when presenting the action sheet, pass a property of the `parentViewController`, e.g. its view or toolbar?

Still, from an engineering perspective I like your idea of using delegation more. It would seem weird to be reading the code for a view controller acting as a delegate for a UIActionSheet, but having no idea why it was displayed in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problems in the `topViewController` (called `FavoritosViewController`) of a container ViewController.

Before to implement the container ViewController, I was using `FavoritosViewController` in a `UITabBarViewController;` and showed an `UIActionSheet` from the tab bar using the method:
`[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];`

When I modified the structure of the project to use a container ViewController instead of the tabBar, it crashed. But likely due to that there were no tabBar now. It works properly substituting this method for the previous one:
`[actionSheet showInView:self.view];`

Hope be useful. Happy new year.